# Thinking Sphinx - geosearching with a has_one polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx

I am trying to do what is described here:
http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/geosearching.html

Except rather than having latitude and longitude columns on my model, I want to do:

```
class Post
  has_one :location, :as => :locationable
end

class User
  has_one :location, :as => :locationable
end

class Location
  belongs_to :locationable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

so that User and Post can both have location records set by locationable_type and locationable_id...  So I did the following in my Post model:

```
define_index do
  has locationable(:id), :as => :locationable_id
  has "RADIANS(locations.lat)", :as => :latitude, :type => :float
  has "RADIANS(locations.lng)", :as => :longitude, :type => :float
end
```

but I get an Unknown column in 'field list' error...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out..  This line:

```
has locationable(:id), :as => :locationable_id
```

Was supposed to be forcing a join...  but it couldn't because there is no such thing as locationable for a post record..  It has_one location..  So it needed to be:

```
define_index do
  has location.locationable_id, :as => :locationable_id
  has "RADIANS(locations.lat)", :as => :latitude, :type => :float
  has "RADIANS(locations.lng)", :as => :longitude, :type => :float
end
```

and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

it looks you made a mis-typo: (as you wrote, you do not have 'locations', you have 'locationable')

```
define_index do
  has locationable(:id), :as => :locationable_id
  has "RADIANS(locationable.lat)", :as => :latitude, :type => :float
  has "RADIANS(locationable.lng)", :as => :longitude, :type => :float
end
```

and please make sure that you have lat, lng columns at 'locations' table (Location model)

Comment: Yeah, I had tried that originally-- and tried again and that also doesn't work.  I was dubious it would work because from reading the sphinx docs, it seems that when you do something like: "RADIANS(locationable.lat)" it is going to talk directly to the database (without ruby/rails) and there is no such thing as locationable as far as the database knows-- that's a magical rails thing.  The actual table name is "locations", so it seems that sphinx needs to reference that, no?

Comment: You might need to add some data because of polymorphic relations.